# cannot import name 'haversine_distances' from 'sklearn.metrics.pairwise'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

`import pysal as ps`

I'm tring to import pysal but I get the following:

cannot import name 'haversine_distances' from 'sklearn.metrics.pairwise'

So I tried: 
`from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine_distances`

and I get the same message. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that your version of scikit-learn is out of date. Try uninstalling and reinstalling scikit-learn from the terminal like so:

```
conda uninstall scikit-learn
```

Confirm, and wait for the packages to be uninstalled. Then, do `conda install scikit-learn` and `conda install pysal` to reinstall the packages. You'll also need to reinstall any other packages that rely on scikit-learn as well.

I had the same issue, and this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

About scikit learn's Haversine, you have to update your scikit-learn to latest version. If you check on scikitlearn website you will find out that this module is implemented in version 0.22.1:

> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html

Comment: Although this has worked for you, you should try to provide answers that will work generically, not only for pycharm users :) (unless the question is specifically about pycharm of course)